# Using as shipping address the value entered as billing address

Tags: 8, commerce

In Drupal Commerce 2 how can we allow a customer to select as shipping address the same address entered as billing address?

Comment: As of now, there is no exact solution for this using commerce module. In my view, one way we can do this using jQuery. The shipping values to copy Billing address values using some checkbox.

Comment: The most recent related work was on profile reuse for the sake of the core address book UI, though I don't believe it specifically related to address copying: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2844920#comment-12715035

The idea was to nail down profile reuse and then add support for copying. It's not quite as straightforward as in 1.x, because 2.x combines the billing address with stored payment methods.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can try to custom jquery event.

1.To create a custom js file in your theme folder (/themes/theme-name/js)

Triger Function Like:

$("select[name='panes[delivery][select_address]']").change(function()
{
//your code
//.....

```
});
```

Thanks